# Code Coverage Success in Sandbox but Error in Production

Tags: deployment, custom-button, sandbox, code-coverage, production

I have 100% code coverage when I tested it in the Sandbox. When I have uploaded the same in the production using changesets, I am getting code coverage error as 53%. What might be the issue. This code for a custom button to send an email for a public group. I have all those deployed in production. Now when I am trying classes, I am getting code coverage error. How to resolve this?

**APex ClasS:**

```
global class memberApproval {

    webservice static boolean callApproval(Id localId) { 
                set<Id> Uid = new set<Id>();
         List<GroupMember> Lst =[Select Id, UserOrGroupId From GroupMember Where GroupId = '00G19000000YJRC'];
         if(Lst.size()>0){
         for(GroupMember g:Lst){
             Uid.add(g.UserOrGroupId);
         }

         if(Uid.size()>0){
         List<User> Lstuser = [select id,email from user where Id In:Uid];
         if(Lstuser.size()>0){

         List<String> EmailIds = new List<string>();


         for(User u:Lstuser){
         EmailIds.add(u.Email);
         }
           //New instance of a single email message
             Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

            // Who you are sending the email to

               mail.setToAddresses( EmailIds  );

               // The email template ID used for the email
               mail.setTemplateId('00X19000000Dm14');
               mail.setTargetObjectId(userinfo.getuserid());      
               mail.setWhatId(localId);   
               mail.setBccSender(false);
               mail.setUseSignature(false);
               mail.setReplyTo('v.reddy@thegordiangroup.com');
               mail.setSenderDisplayName('Confirmation of Order Quote');
               mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);  

            Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
         }
         }
         }
        return true;               
    }
}
```

**Test Class**

```
@isTest 

public with sharing class Test_Classnow {
  static testMethod void validateHelloWorld() {

    Group testGroup = new Group();
        testGroup.Name = 'testGroup';
        testGroup.DeveloperName = 'ABC';
        INSERT testGroup;

         Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='Standard User']; 
        User u = new User(Alias = 'standt', Email='standsdgser@testorg.com', 
            EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='Testing', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US', 
            LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = p.Id, 
            TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', UserName='stangsgduser@testorg.com');

            insert u;


            GroupMember gm= new GroupMember(); 
            gm.GroupId=testGroup.id;
            gm.UserOrGroupId = u.id;
            insert gm;

            // insert opportunity and pass opp id instead of gm.id

      boolean result= memberApproval.callApproval(gm.id);
      system.assertequals(result,true);

  }



}
```

Comment: I would recommend you push all your test classes first to the production and then push the remain apex classes/controllers. Also remember to fill any data in production which is included as part of your tests, like custom settings, labels etc.

Comment: @codeinprogress I have used hardcoded values in my code. Id's of template and group. But when I deployed the email template and Group in production the values change. So is that the problem? How can I do to prevent hard coding values into the code.

Comment: Query for your ID. Id myGroupId = [SELECT Id from Group WHERE DeveloperName = 'your_group_name' LIMIT 1].Id. Then use :myGroup.Id in your query for GroupMember

Comment: Hey @frontendloader ... Sorry I have not understood. Could you please include that in my code. It will help me a lot in solving this.

Comment: also - the email templateId is hard-coded - this can create deployment issues as well

Comment: How to make sure the code works without hardcoding? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This apex class is getting 100% code coverage but you say on deployment, code coverage is at 53%?

Is it possible that the rest of your code in Sandbox accumulates to 53% code coverage when averaged together? On deployment, Salesforce will look at total coverage, not just the code you are deploying.

Answer (score 0):

I did used custom labels to resolve this. Here is the following code changes in the Class.

```
global class memberApproval {

webservice static boolean callApproval(Id localId) { 
            set<Id> Uid = new set<Id>();
            String grpId = Label.GroupId;
     List<GroupMember> Lst =[Select Id, UserOrGroupId From GroupMember Where GroupId =: grpId];
     if(Lst.size()>0){
     for(GroupMember g:Lst){
         Uid.add(g.UserOrGroupId);
     }

     if(Uid.size()>0){
     List<User> Lstuser = [select id,email from user where Id In:Uid];
     if(Lstuser.size()>0){

     List<String> EmailIds = new List<string>();


     for(User u:Lstuser){
     EmailIds.add(u.Email);
     }
       //New instance of a single email message
         Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

        // Who you are sending the email to

           mail.setToAddresses( EmailIds  );
        String templateIdVal= Label.TemplateId;
           mail.setTemplateId(templateIdVal);
           mail.setTargetObjectId(userinfo.getuserid());      
           mail.setWhatId(localId);   
           mail.setBccSender(false);
           mail.setUseSignature(false);
           mail.setReplyTo('v.reddy@thegordiangroup.com');
           mail.setSenderDisplayName('Confirmation of Order Quote');
           mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);  

        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
     }
     }
     }
    return true;               
}
```

}